# out of memory when reinstalling aplication

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, out-of-memory

I'm desperate.

I create an application using sqlite an it was working fine until I submit an update to the apple store.
when my application is reinstalled and I tried to open a db connection I got an "out of memory" issue.

I've tried lots of stuff to solve this issue, but until today I was unable to solve this.

I use the code below to open db's connection:

```
-(Boolean)openConectionSQLiteDb
{
        if (sqlite3_open([[GeneralFunction getInfoFromUserDefault:@"dbpath"] UTF8String], &db) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Failed to open database!");
            NSLog(@"%s",sqlite3_errmsg(statement));
            //[GeneralFunction setDb:[[DbInteraction alloc] init:[GeneralFunction getDbName]]];
            {
                NSLog(@"Failed to open database! >>%@",[GeneralFunction getInfoFromUserDefault:@"dbpath"]);
              //  NSLog(@"222%s",sqlite3_errmsg(statement));
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);

            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            sqlite3_exec(db, "PRAGMA foreign_keys = on", NULL, NULL, NULL);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

And the code below is used to insert date on the database:

```
-(Boolean)insertOrReplace:(NSDictionary *)elementoToInsert inTable:(NSString *)tableName
{
    if([self openConectionSQLiteDb])
    {
        NSString * insert = [self createInsertStringWith:elementoToInsert in:tableName];
        insert = [insert stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"INSERT" withString:@"INSERT OR REPLACE "];
        const char *insert_stmt = [insert UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insert_stmt,
                           -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            sqlite3_close(db);
          //  NSLog(@"FECHOU");
            return true;
        }
        NSLog(@"INSERT ERROR %s",sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }

    sqlite3_close(db);
    NSLog(@"FECHOU");


    return false;

}
```

I'm also use this code to copy the Db file to a writable path when it necessary:

```
-(id)init:(NSString *) dbName
{
    self = [super init];
    nomeDb = dbName;


    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *filemngr = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDbPath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:nomeDb];

   // NSLog(@"%@",[GeneralFunction getInfoFromUserDefault:@"dbpath"]);

    NSString * lastPath =[GeneralFunction getInfoFromUserDefault:@"dbpath"];
    success = [filemngr fileExistsAtPath:lastPath];
    if(!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Arquivo não existe  nesse Directorio >%@",lastPath);
            success = [filemngr fileExistsAtPath:writableDbPath];
        if(!success)
        {
            NSLog(@"Arquivo não existe  nesse Directorio >%@",writableDbPath);
            NSString *defaultDbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:nomeDb];
            success = [filemngr copyItemAtPath:defaultDbPath toPath:writableDbPath error:&error];
            NSLog(@"Copiou Para :%@",writableDbPath);
            if (!success)
            {
                NSLog(@"Arquivo não existe  nesse Directorio pela seguanda vez >%@",writableDbPath);
            //[status setText:[error localizedDescription]];
           /* UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!"
                                                            message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];*/
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Achou 2");
                NSMutableDictionary * dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
             //   NSLog(@"%@",writableDbPath);
                [dic setObject:writableDbPath forKey:@"dbpath"];
                [GeneralFunction saveTeacherInfo:dic];
                writablePath = writableDbPath;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Banco esta em %@",writableDbPath);
        }
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Achou");
    }

   // [bd executeUpdate:@"PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON"];
    return self;

}
```

So when I install the application for the first time, it works fine. But if I run the applications again (It happens when I submit an update too) I got the LOG error "Failed to open database out of memory".

Someone please help me, I'm almost getting fired.

PS: I'm sorry for my terrible English. ;D

Comment: You need to add database file in application bundle and then from `[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:` method load database. Please confirm that.

Comment: What is the 'dbpath' when it fails?

Comment: it is the directory where i copy the dataBase on Library folder.

Comment: Kampai, yeah man i'm doing this.

Comment: I just add on the post the code that i use to init my db and copy it when it's necessary . if both you could take a look. it would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YEAH GUYS, finally I could solve my issue.
It was happening because when I was checking if there was a Database already copied in my writable path, in the TRUE condition I forgot to update my internal path that refers to the DB. For that reason when I was trying to open a connection, it was returning me the error because I was looking for the database in wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

sqlite reports "out of memory" errors incorrectly at times. Usually if this occurs after an app update, it's because you have a bug in your sqlite access code. If your database schema has changed between app versions, but you didn't make sure that your database calls are backwards-compatible, you will frequently see this error.

If your `CREATE TABLE` statements aren't followed by `ALTER TABLE` statements to bring your schema up to speed when the `CREATE` fails because the table already exists, you run the risk of making database calls that are not backwards-compatible.

Comment: but i don't change anything on the Db structure .
In i don't know if it's make diference, but i create the database using a firefox plugin and import to my project's bundle .